# WatchFolder() Function From Autohotkey Community

Tags: autohotkey

This is beyond my comfort zone of `Sendinput` and `Sleep`.
Any help as to what am doing wrong, would much appreciated.

I have found this function [WatchFolder() - updated on 2021-10-14 - AutoHotkey Community](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8384&hilit=watch)  and using some of the examples shared on that thread I was ables to put this together:

```
#Persistent

#Include, <WatchFolder>

WatchFolder("C:\Temp\", "ReportFunction", false, 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 |16 | 32 | 64 | 256)

Return

ReportFunction(Directory, Changes) {

 For Each, Change In Changes {

       Action := Change.Action

       Name := Change.Name

       If (Action = 3)

         Run, Notepad

}

}
```

I figured out how to watch for all the other events correctly (deleted, added etc etc). I am having problems wih the file modified event.  The event occurs twice.
so in the above ebove example notepad is run twice. If I set `Run` to open `.Url` it will also open twice.

I dont know why. I tried changing a bunch of things in my `ReportFunction` but nothing worked.
PS: `Watchfolder` function is saved in `Documents\Autohotkey\Lib` folder and I have made no changes to it, it is as I downloaded it.

Comment: Seeing as the function is from 8 years ago, I recommend posting it (and supporting functions as well). Not everyone using AHK has been using it as long as that, but are still familiar with AHK and can help.

Comment: Does this work in AHK v2?

Answer (score 1):

As I have checked myself, it works just fine if you modify the files in the folder yourself but while using the downloads folder like your example script in the ahk forum post or using temp folder it will execute multiple times as normal. The reason is, it's keep updating and modifying the file while downloading, you can check it as well if you download a large sized file, size will change time to time. Just to try, I downloaded your example in the ahk forum and it opened 3 notepad windows while just downloading 342bytes sized file. Temp folder is just the same, files keep written and deleted there, not easy to track and execute by those folders like that. Try to set a custom folder location and check it by modifying the files by yourself. If you must use those folders maybe you can add a sleep like 5 secs after Run command but I don't know how efficient it would be.

Comment: Hey Thanks so much for taking the time explain this to me, I am not home now but I will test this out soon as I can and get back to you